# common controls pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a webapp (vs2012) that has several pages, in a few pages of some common controls.
I don't want to use the Master Page.
and if I use the `UserControl` can I access to the controls of UC?

Please suggest a good way

Comment: Can you add some code? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I still have not started writing code!!The pages have common control.I want to decide what method to use.

Answer (score 0):

can I access to the controls of UC?

answer is Yes
You can expose public property on your UC for every control on you UC.
And using these property you can access these controls
You can go throught this link
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Santhi.M/PassingValuesfrmUCtoASPX11212005050040AM/PassingValuesfrmUCtoASPX.aspx

Comment: Can I access button and fire event Click on the same page or hide controls?